# How to search for files with certain attributes in Linux

Tags: bash

First time posting and did much searching for the answer. I did see some answers but not exactly what I was looking for. What I need to do is write a script to display the files whose sizes are in a specific range without using the "find" command. This script takes two arguments as the lower bound and upper bound of the file size and prints out a list of filenames as well as their sizes. I am VERY new to this but any help will do. Thanks!

What I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "You need at least 2 arguments"
    exit 1
fi

lowerbound=$1
upperbound=$2
total=0

for i in *
do
    set -- $(ls -l "$i")
    echo $i: $5 bytes

    if [ $5 -ge $lowerbound ]
    then
        if [ $5 -le $upperbound ]
        then
            echo $i: $5
        fi
    fi

    then
        echo "Lowerbound needs to be at least 80"

done     
exit 1
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- get the file size like this: `size=$( stat -c '%s' "$i" )`

Comment: With bash, unless you have a specific reason to use `[ ... ]` you should prefer `[[ ... ]]`

Comment: Use consistent indentation.  If you don't then a kitten dies.  What is the final `then` doing?

Comment: Why can't you use `find`?  Either this is homework or I suspect you are pursuing a sub-optimal solution...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slow solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
recover_my_hung_system() {
    # just in case ;)
    pidof bash | sudo xargs renice -n 10
    sudo renice -n -19 -p $$
}

# renice -n 10 -p $$ # give low prio to this script
export BLOCK_SIZE=1;
lower=${1:-5000}
upper=${2:-20000}
declare out=()
for i in *; do
    if [[ -f "$i" ]]; then
        size=$(stat -c%s "$i")
        if [[ $size -gt $lower ]] && [[ $size -lt $upper ]]; then
            out+=($size "$i")
        fi
    fi
done

if [[ ${#out} -gt 0 ]]; then
    pwd
    printf '%d %s\n' "${out[@]}"
fi

for i in *; do
    if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then
        ( cd "$i";
          bash $0 $lower $upper
        ) # & # -- uncomment the ampersand if you have too much ram.
    fi
done
```